# Samsung TV App RTMP Streaming

Tags: samsung-smart-tv

I am new to smart tv app development. I want to develop an app that stream a video from following link

RTMP: rtmp://madanichannel.videocdn.scaleengine.net/madanichannel-live/play
Stream Name: mc720

HTTP: http://madanichannel.videocdn.scaleengine.net/madanichannel-iphone/play/mc720.smil/playlist.m3u8

Platform: Samsung Smart TV
Model: UE46F8090
SDK = 5.1

I tried tutrials but still not working

In case of http link above on emulator it works for 30 secs but does not work at all on tv
in case of rtmp it niether work on tv nor on emulator

Attached is the code.. i tried lots of sample code but none of them is 
working...

Code: https://www.dropbox.com/s/xqjr9o0g5vtgyzk/VideoDemo.zip?dl=0

kindly let me know what i am doing wrong

Your Help is highly appreciated
Thanks
Adil

Comment: Hi, I'm afraid the question won't work in its current form. Can you post relevent parts of your code here? Also we'd need some more information than just "doesn't work", what exactly is going wrong where? Do you see any log messages, error messages....?

Comment: I want to develop an app that stream a video from following link

RTMP: rtmp://madanichannel.videocdn.scaleengine.net/madanichannel-live/play
Stream Name: mc720 
HTTP: http://madanichannel.videocdn.scaleengine.net/madanichannel-iphone/play/mc720.smil/playlist.m3u8


Platform: Samsung Smart TV
Model: UE46F8090
SDK = 5.1

I tried tutrials but still not working

In case of http link above on emulator it works for 30 secs but does not work at all on tv

in case of rtmp it niether work on tv nor on emulator

kindly let me know what i am doing wrong

Comment: I'm afraid I don't have knowledge in this field but someone else may have. Can you edit all that information into your question?

Comment: Hi, I strongly recommend to use native samsung player object, where m3u8 files are supported without problems. :)